# No notification is shown on iOS (sent with Firebase) while the app is in the background

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, nativescript, firebase-notifications

I have a (Nativescript) iOS client app that should be able to receive a push notification sent by Firebase. It actually does receive data when the app is in the frontend, but as the documentation states, iOS should detect an incoming notification (when the app is in the background) and display the notification.

This last part just doesn't seem to work. I tried a lot, but can't figure out what's going on here.

I'm sending the notification by using the Firebase console. There's just nothing happening on my iPhone here, no sound, no badge, nothing!
While Firebase claims everything just works fine...?!

Can anybody help me?

---

Okay, so I guess I wasn't very specific, so let me add some code below.

I am posting this code to Firebase (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) to trigger the push notification:

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=[MY_KEY_HERE]

{
  "to" : "[FIREBASE_DEVICE_ID_HERE]",
  "priority": "high",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "Howto write a great body?",
    "title" : "Some title...",
    "sound" : "default"
  }
}
```

As you can see, this is a **notification** message, not a **data** message, so it should trigger a popup, badge, sound, or whatever on iOS...right?

As I mentioned before, I am able to receive this json data, but only if my app is in the foreground... So the Firebase-device-id is absolutely right and also is the authorization key.

What else should I try?

Comment: While this is a question, it doesn't really adhere to the guidelines for asking a question here on stackoverflow. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complere and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be best to post your code that is failing as the issue could be a typo, or a configuration issue or something that was entirely overlooked. That code will help us, help you to get an accurate answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right, so I specified a bit more...

Answer (score 1):

FCM Data-Messages are not displayed while the app is in background :

`On iOS, FCM stores the message and delivers it only when the app is in the foreground and has established a FCM connection.`

Source here : [FCM Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Be sure to sens Notification and not a Data message

Comment: It's definitely a notification message and not a data message, see code sample above...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are disconnecting from Firebase with such command

```
[[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
```

Could you tell if you can send message via APNS from your computer (without Firebase)? Example file to send such message can be found somewhere in this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial .

Comment: I am posting/triggering also by using Postman (Chrome Extension) that can send raw data. This gives me the same result... See the code sample above...